# Is there any data loss during dual boot?

Tags: 12.04

I am currently using ubuntu on my laptop......Now I  want to dual boot windows alongside ubuntu....I want to ask will I be loosing data that is currently present in ubuntu if I dual boot windows

Answer (score 1):

It is strongly recommended to first install the Windows OS and then afterwards install Ubuntu.
But this means that you will have to wipe your whole disk and therefore all your data will be lost.

You can backup your `/home` folder to another disk and restore the content into your new Ubuntu installation.

For this purpose the easiest way is to do it with `deja-dup` which is included in Ubuntu.
Another alternative could be, that you copy the data you want to keep manually to another drive.

Answer (score 0):

Fist of all. You cannot "dual boot" in the sense that two operating systems are running at the same time. You can only "dual boot" in the sense that you have the option to boot either.

Secondly: You should specify what you are attempting to do. I'll try to cover the cases that come to mind:

### Installation

If you have data on a partition (thus on a disk) and you install an operating system (windows or Linux) or parts of it onto this partition, then the partition gets (in most cases) formatted and the data on it gets lost, consequentially.

In contrast what was written in another answer: I am pretty sure that installing Windows does not wipe the entire drive, but only - as I mentioned - the partition it is installed in. That the entire disk would be wiped would (obviously) only be the case if partition would span the entire disk. But then you would need another disk for the second operating system.

### After installation: Running one system after the other

#### Shutting down before restarting

If you shut down one operating system properly it does not effect anything on the other operating system.

#### Hibernation (suspend to disk) before restarting

If you are in Windows and hibernate (suspend to disk) and then boot into Ubuntu you may experience data loss. Thus you should disable fast startup in Windows settings: http://www.h-online.com/open/features/Linux-and-Windows-8-Fast-Startup-puts-data-at-risk-1780640.html

The same goes for the scenario when you are in Ubuntu, hibernate and go into Windows: https://superuser.com/a/136814

#### Suspend to RAM before restarting

I don't think it is possible to change the operating system if you suspend to RAM.